# Variables defined *and* undefined

Tags: makefile

I guess this makes sense somehow, but I can't grasp why: In the following code, I get **both** warnings (note that the original code was indented with tabs):

```
define variable-definition
    ifndef $1
        $(warning $1 is undefined)
    else
        $(warning $1 is defined)
    endif
endef
```

PS: I want to check whether the variable with the name passed as `$1` exists, not whether `$1` was passed.

PPS: Dedenting the entire thing doesn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beta's analysis of the root cause is correct, you're not escaping your `$` on the `$(warning)` calls. Here's how I'd fix it:

```
define variable-def
  ifndef $1
    $$(warning $1 is undefined)
  else
    $$(warning $1 is defined)
  endif
endef
FOO=bar
$(eval $(call variable-def,FOO))
```

Note that I am indenting with spaces, not tabs. If you indent with tabs, you get this error: `*** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`

This uses GNUisms, but so does your sample (I think).

Comment: +1. Escaping the warnings... Oh, that's good. [*gnashes teeth*]

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's giving you both warnings is that when you call this function (i.e. expand this variable), Make expands the variables within it, including *both* warnings. This happens before if tries to evaluate the `ifndef` (and probably fails). Make simply doesn't handle conditionals the way you want.

Here's a way to do it, slightly clunky, but effective. (To do it really smoothly as a function would probably require a considerable amount of black magic). Write a separate makefile called `variable-definition`:

```
# In makefile variable-definition

ifndef $(FOO)
 $(warning $(FOO) is undefined)
else
 $(warning $(FOO) is defined)
endif
```

Then in the main makefile:

```
# In the main makefile

bar = something
FOO := bar

include variable-definition

FOO := baz

include variable-definition
```

Comment: I wouldn't say a "considerable" amount -- see my answer.

Comment: @Jack Kelly: Once again you have defeated me, but we shall meet again, and revenge shall be mine.